# How do sim cards in Thailand work?

Tags: cellphones, thailand

I am a tourist in Thailand and am a little confused about the packaging of SIM cards I see in stores like 7/11.

They seem to have days marked on them, eg: `5g, 15 days, 150thb.`

Does this mean that I have 15 days to use the SIM card before it expires?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this mean that I have 15 days to use the SIM card before it expires?

It means the SIM card will expire 15 days after it is activated.

[image]

(FYI: [Are all prepaid SIM cards referred to as Tourist SIM cards in Thailand? Or are there some prepaid SIM cards “for locals”?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/156433/1810))

Once it expires, one can buy some x-day (1 ≤ x ≤ 30) additional package using the same SIM card, e.g. via https://topping.truemoveh.com/ for [TrueMoveH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueMove_H) SIM Cards. Typically one "tops up" (= adds) the money by going to a 7-eleven (they'll ask for the SIM card phone number + cash: no credit card accepted for tops-up, I don't know why), then go on https://topping.truemoveh.com ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200611020802/http://web.archive.org/screenshot/https://topping.truemoveh.com/)) to select which package to purchase (in this example, 1k THB were topped-up at a 7-eleven):

[image]

Or one can buy top-ups in some stores:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm.  Isnt it normally 30 days?

Comment: @JonGrah depends on the SIM card

Comment: Do they let you use it without registering your id card/passport? Most shops now require it. But not sure if you can just pop it in and get any use before mandatory registration.

Comment: @JonGrah Sorry I forgot whether they ask for some ID in Thailand.

Comment: I went in and got a SIM card today. Just to clarify the ones in the photo are for top-ups, though the SIM cards themselves are similar with an expiry. You will need a passport to get them.

Comment: @MeltingDog thanks, I need to improve my Thai :) I'm curious in the image where do you see those are top-ups?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I didn't. I took one to a 7/11 counter and they told me. They had the real SIMs behind the counter.

Comment: Credit card is not accepted due to the fees, they would eat almost all of the store's margin on the top ups. Countries where credit cards have become ubiquitous like the US stores just bake in that % to the base price. This hasn't happened in countries like Thailand where credit card usage is still very low (something like 1% of transactions last time I checked). QR code payment / bank transfer which is totally free is more common for this stuff. You can use a card to pay if you pay the phone company directly, I guess in that case there is one less party taking a cut. I pay AIS by Visa.